# TMux: how to flip pane layout horizontally / vertically

Tags: tmux

Let's say I have 3 panes opened in my tmux session, laid out like this:

```
|----|--|--|
| 1  | 2| 3|
|----|--|--|
```

What I would like to do, is flip this layout horizontally, so it looks like this:

```
|--|--|----|
| 3| 2| 1  |
|--|--|----|
```

Is there an easy way (preferably a shortcut) to do this?

Comment: Is pane `1` larger than the other two panes and if yes, does that need to be conserved?

Comment: I have posted an answer, but I admit, it's not a very good one. Looking forward to better answers!

Comment: Yes, precisely, I'm looking for a way to preserve the pane size. Right now I have a docking station which makes my two monitors merge into one display in `xrandr`. This means that I often have one terminal window spread across both of those monitors.

Comment: I understand. Wouldn't it make more sense to have two desktops, for two monitors, instead of a large one? Is there a specific reason why you want to have one desktop only? What windows manager do you use?

Comment: I have one desktop because of hardware limitations, not choice :). I use i3wm, so one terminal window spread across both displays is a must (alt+enter shortcut, etc.)

Comment: I don't understand. You have two monitors (laptop and external one, I presume?). Why do you span your desktop over both monitors, instead of having one workspace on each monitor? This is also the default on i3, so I probably just misunderstand the question.

Comment: @pfnuesel I have a laptop that sits on a docking station, to which two monitors are connected via two display ports. Unfortunately, to the OS (because all of the crtc magic that is happening thanks to the hardware) they are seen as one large widescreen. So essentially, I have a big bezel in the middle of my primary workspace. In order to preserve some sanity while working, I use i3wm. Because of the alt-enter shortcut I use a single terminal window, spread over both of these monitors, and utilize tmux to manage it. That's why sometimes I want to flip the pane layout horizontally.

Comment: I forgot to mention: in my configuration alt+enter makes the focus jump to the opened terminal window, not spawn a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `swap-pane -s 0 -t 2` will swap the source and target panes for you, leaving the one in the middle unchanged.

You could then write a small script to call `list-panes` which will tell you the current sizes, eg

```
0: [40x23] [history 2/2000, 760 bytes] %0 (active)
1: [19x23] [history 2/2000, 466 bytes] %3
2: [19x23] [history 2/2000, 466 bytes] %4
```

and then issue `resize-pane` commands for each pane to set a new size in the x direction.  For example, create `/tmp/myscript` with

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux swap-pane -s 0 -t 2
tmux list-panes |
awk '
$1~/^[0-9]:$/ { x[$1] = substr($2,2)+0 }
END { print "tmux resize-pane -t 0 -x " x["2:"]
      print "tmux resize-pane -t 1 -x " x["1:"]
      print "tmux resize-pane -t 2 -x " x["0:"] }' |
sh
```

and do `chmod +x /tmp/myscript`, then add to your `~/.tmux.conf` a binding such as for letter `o`, typed after your usual prefix key:

```
bind-key o run-shell /tmp/myscript
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `swap-pane` command. By default this is bound to `C-b {` and `C-b }`, assuming `C-b` is your `tmux` prefix.

In your specific case, you can focus on pane `1`, and do `C-b }` twice. Then you focus on pane `3` and do `C-b {` once.

There are many ways to achieve this, you can also use `C-b C-o`, no matter where your focus is, and then focus on pane `3` and do `C-b {`.

If you happen to do this often, you can make a shortcut in your `~/.tmux.conf`.

Note, that none of these commands preserve the size of your panes. If the left pane used to be larger than the other two, that will still be the case after moving panes around. That means pane `1` will become smaller and pane `3` will grow larger. I don't know if it's possible to conserve pane sizes.